# Xamarin Forms Android System Exception "Android only allows one navigation page on screen at a time"

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Recently i decided to give [Xamarin Forms](http://www.xamarin.com/forms) a try, so i started migrating my Windows Phone / Android Xamarin project, to the new "Forms" format.

After migrating two simple screens (views), the code runs just fine on my Windows Phone, but it crashes on the Android Platform. I am using two devices to test the code, with no emulator to avoid unecessary headaches.

The exception raised on the android platform is: `System.Exception: Android only allows one navigation page on screen at a time`.

The problem is not related to the "View" class itself, since it doesn`t happen once i set it as the "start screen" for the Android.

I'm afraid the problem is related to the fact that i am "Pushing" two screens via the "Navigation.PushAsync(...)" method provided by Xamarin.

Any ideas on how do actually fix it ?

**EDIT:**

[Code Sample](http://pastebin.com/QbmQ0N7A)

**Overview:** The "MainView.cs" is just a content page with a label on the top, followed by two buttons alligned vertically.

**How to reproduce the exception:** Click on "Get All Users" button on the mainview. I have modified the code to push the same view once the button is clicked, instead of pushing another view (The view that has a listview of users, which i haven't included, just to make it simple).  Once the button is clicked, it will navigate to a new instance of "MainView" by calling "Navigation.PushAsync(...)". This will trigger the exception after the screen is loaded.

Comment: Please post the code that is causing the exception.

Comment: Added a code sample with some minor overview of the exception and how to reproduce it. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Please post code inline, properly formatted, instead of using an external link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nesting Navigation pages.  This is not necessary.  Try this instead:

```
public class ViewsHandler
{
        public static Page GetMainPage()
        {
            return new MainView();
        }

        public static Page GetUsersListPage()
        {
            return new UsersListView ();
        }
}

public class MainActivity : AndroidActivity
{
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Initializing Xamarin Form
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);

            // create a single NavigationPage wrapping your content
            SetPage (new NavigationPage(ViewsHandler.GetMainPage()));
        }
}
```

Comment: Solved my problem. Would you mind explaining a little bit more, WHY does it work?

Comment: In your original code, you were pushing a NavigationPage onto an already existing navigation stack.  You only need one NavigationPage in a hierarchy.